# How to create a Unix shell script project in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

I want to clone my Git repo into NetBeans (which only contains a Unix shell script).

When I'm asked by NetBeans if I would like to create a project for this repo, I only find Java, PHP, Web, C/C++, etc.. projects groups, but I want an bare-bone group, it's just a shell script file, what to do?

I don't want Ant or building anything, I just want to use NetBeans as an editor and commit changes to Git.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here goes, after cloning the project from GitHub, I was asked by NetBeans if would like to create a project, so I chose yes, then:

1) I chose "Java" under Categories and "Java Free-Form Project" under Projects

2) I created an Ant build file "build.xml" from sample on https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html

3) After creating the project I moved the "build.xml" to directory "nbproject" and updated "nbproject/project.xml" to point to the new build file destination

4) I updated the "build.xml" tasks to copy source files and license file in case of build and zip the build files in case of distribution

5) Finally I had to add a ".gitignore" fie to the root directory to ignore the "build" and "dist" directories from Git

After this I commited and pushed the whole NB project to GitHub you can find the final files here https://github.com/asaeles/sql_runner

Answer (score -1):

for such simple projects, netbeans would be kind of an overkill, I believe notepad++ and normal git shell would suffice